# Dart Sass import Error, can't find Stylesheet to import

Tags: sass, bulma

I have some problems trying to compile bulma.
My Filestructure:

```
project folder
├── bulma
│   ├── bulma0.9.4
│   │   └── bulma
│   │       └── bulma.sass
│   ├─── dart-sass
│   │    └── sass.bat
│   ├─── mystyles.scss
│   └── compile.bat
│    
└── src
    └── styles
```

Compile.bat Content:

```
"%~dp0\dart-sass\sass" --no-source-map mystyles.scss:../src/styles/mybulma.css
```

mystyles.scss Content:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import "/bulma-0.9.4/bulma/bulma.sass";
```

So when I run compile.bat I get the following error:

```
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │ @import "/bulma-0.9.4/bulma/bulma.sass";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
```

Any Ideas why, do I need to use some other filepath?

Comment: You should be able to just do `@import 'bulma'`. Also you shouldn't use absolute URL's